# Mock exit() function in PHP

Tags: php, unit-testing, reflection, abstract-syntax-tree, monkeypatching

For a library I am writing I would like to be able to mock the `exit` PHP function.

I tried to use [php-mock](https://github.com/php-mock/php-mock) to provide a namespaced version of `exit`, something like

```
namespace MyNamespace;

function exit()
{
    // my mocked version of the function
}
```

But this creates problems to the parser, which throws the following `ParseError`: `syntax error, unexpected 'exit' (T_EXIT), expecting '('`.

Is there any other way to mock a built in function without incurring in parsing problems? Should I try to modify the AST with something like [BetterReflection](https://github.com/Roave/BetterReflection)?

Comment: exit is a language construct, you can't mock it.

Comment: Exit is a language construct, not a function.  For that reason, I don't think you'll be able to replace it.

Comment: I think even though the premise of this question was a flawed assumption, it  does deserve a +1, especially given the signal-to-noise ration in the php tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comments, I guess that mocking language constructs is not feasible.

To test `exit()` I ended up spawning other processes with `exec` and asserting on their output and exist status